# mongoimport jsonArray works fine with 64bit build, but throws exception in 32bit

Tags: json, windows, mongodb, arrays

I'm running MongoDB standalone servers in two different systems - Windows 8.1 Pro 64 Bit (MongoDB 2.6 64 Bit) and Windows 7 Pro 32 Bit(MongoDB 2.6 32 Bit)

While **mongoimport csv works fine in both systems**, I'm facing an exception while running mongoimport --jsonArray in the 32 Bit build installed in the Windows 7 system. The limitation is that the Windows 7 system is a remote machine with only a 32 bit OS option so that cannot be changed.

**mongoimport --jsonArray works fine for the 64 bit build** :

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongoimport -host localhost -d test -c <CollectionName> < data.json --jsonArray
connected to: localhost
Mon Apr 28 03:22:16.263 check 9 7343
Mon Apr 28 03:22:16.264 imported 7343 objects
```

---

**mongoimport --jsonArray fails for the 32 bit build** : (Shown below is a subset of the JSON array. The JSON array file size is 432 KB only so the 2 GB limitation shouldn't be an issue either)

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongoimport -host localhost -d test -c  <CollectionName> < data.json --jsonArray
connected to: localhost

exception: Invalid JSON passed to mongoimport: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse
: Expecting '{': offset:0 of:∩╗┐
[
    {
        Name:"Colonia del Sacramento",
        loc:[-34.47999901,-57.84000247]
    },
    {
        Name:"Trinidad",
        loc:[-33.54399894,-56.90099656]
    },
    {
        Name:"Fray Bentos",
        loc:[-33.13899903,-58.30399747]
    }
]
```

---

I'm running mongoimport from the terminal and not from the Mongo shell. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I modified my json input file to represent a json document in each line (subset)

```
{Name:"Hamilton",loc:[-37.77826936,175.2895781]}
{Name:"Blenheim",loc:[-41.51351724,173.9549575]}
{Name:"Dunedin",loc:[-45.8854231,170.4910157]}
{Name:"Wellington",loc:[-41.29998785,174.7832659]}
{Name:"Christchurch",loc:[-43.5350216,172.6300232]}
```

and changed the mongoimport command to

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongoimport --db test --collection   <collectionName> --type json --file data.json
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2014-04-29T05:34:07.084-0600 check 9 7343
2014-04-29T05:34:07.101-0600 imported 7343 objects
```